# Hapi Joi validation - validate single string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, hapi.js

I want to do some basic validation on a single string which is a request header `X-Value`. Below is my attempt.

The problem is it always returns 'success' even if no `X-Value` header is present.

```
  const mySchema = Joi.string().min(2).max(30).required();
  const value = req.get('X-Value');
  const { myError } = mySchema.validate(value);
  if(myError){
    return res.status(401).json({ error: myError.details[0].message });
  }

  return res.send('success');
```

How can I validate this without putting it into an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are destructuring `myError` from validate function. But there is no such thing. You need to destruct `error` and use like this:

```js
const mySchema = Joi.string().min(2).max(30).required();
const value = req.get('X-Value');
const { error } = mySchema.validate(value);

if (error) {
  return res.status(401).json({ error: error.details[0].message });
}

return res.send("success");
```